# Building a blog or FAQ section from YAML files only in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, yaml

I just finished building a new Rails application and now I want to build a simple (but multilingual) blog style FAQ section with entries containing a `question`, an `answer` and a `category` each.

Is there a way to build this kind of thing with YAML-files or do I need to build an entire controller plus model from scratch to get this sort of functionality?

The FAQ section will be maintained by *me* only, so using YAML-files would be an option.

What I have in mind is something like this:

```
# faq.yml

faq:
  payment:
    entry1:
      question: "How can I pay?"
      answer: "You can pay by credit card or PayPal."
    entry2:
      question: "Who coded this app?"
      answer: "The best coder ever!"
```

Can this be done at all in Rails? Can somebody point me to a link or tutorial?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go either way. You will need controller/view functionality, but a model isn't necessary. If you want to use the above YAML code, you'd be able to read it like so:

```
# In your FaqController:
@faq = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/faq.yaml")

# In index.html.erb
<%- @faq['faq'].each do |subject, entries| %>
  <h1><%= subject %></h1>
  <%- entries.each do |entry| %>
    <h2><%= entry['question'] %></h2>
    <p><%= entry['answer'] %></p>
  <%- end %>
<%- end %>
```

Of course, this could be more prone to errors and harder to maintain than using a database-driven model and you will probably want to cache the YAML file for the lifetime of your application to reduce I/O operations.

Comment: Ok, looks good. Thanks. Why would be this be more error prone than a DB driven model though?

Comment: I said it *could* be more error prone. I say that because you're depending on YAML and have no real input validation for changes. That is of course also the case with locale files, so with proper tests you will be able to prevent errors.